# Dynamically inject Vue 2 component from shortcode

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I have a form in an admin area where users can input text with shortcodes in them:

> Heat oven at [temp c=200]

What I want is that `temp` shortcode to be parsed and transformed into a Vue 2 component when shown in the front-end.

Here's a simplified `Temperature.vue` component:

```
<template>
    <span class="temperature">
        {{ celsius }}&deg;C
    </span>
</template>

<script>
    import { mapGetters, mapActions } from 'vuex'

    export default {
        props: ['celsius'],
        name: 'temperature'
    }
</script>
```

And here's a simplified `Instructions.vue` component which will parse and render the text with shortcodes:

```
<template>
    <div v-html="parseShortcodes(text)"></div>
</template>

<script>
    import ShortcodeParser from 'meta-shortcodes'
    import Temperature from 'Temperature.vue'

    export default {

        data: () => {
            return {
                text: 'Heat oven at [temp c=200]',
                parser: ShortcodeParser()
            }
        },
        components: [
            Temperature
        ],
        methods: {
            parseShortcodes(text) {
                return this.parser.parse(text)
            }
        },
        created() {
            this.parser.add('temp', function(options) {
                return '<temperature :celsius="'+options.c+'"></temperature>'
            })
        }
    }
</script>
```

The parsing works fine, and the substitution is printed in the front-end. But the `<temperature>` tag is rendered literally and not as a Vue component, which is somewhat expected.

> Heat oven at <temperature :celsius="200"></temperature>

What I can't seem to wrap my head around is what step I should take for it to actually transform into the `Temperature` component which I have defined. Is it even possible? Are there more orthodox ways of doing this which I am missing?

There is also the security concern of using `v-html` to render the text. I do not necessarily want this to be there, but I'm guessing it's even more far-fetched to expect the `Temperature` component to appear from an escaped string. I can always sanitise prior to insertion on database, but I'd still like to avoid `v-html` if at all possible.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In order to make your example work you'll need to use the render function of your Instructions component. In the render function you can create a new Vue Component, lets say 'intruction', to which you'll pass the string that resulted from shortcode parse to use as template. In that component declaration you'll append the Temperature component as a child and it will render the prop that you've passed. And that's it. The example follows:

Instructions.vue

```
<script>
    import ShortcodeParser from 'meta-shortcodes'
    import Temperature from 'Temperature.vue'

    export default {

        data: () => {
            return {
                text: 'Heat oven at [temp c=200]',
                parser: ShortcodeParser()
            }
        },
        methods: {
            parseShortcodes(text) {
                return this.parser.parse(text)
            }
        },
        render (createElement) {

            const template = this.parseShortcodes(this.text) //returns something like this <div class="intruction">'Heat oven at <temperature :celsius="200"></temperature>'</div>

            var component = Vue.component('instruction', {
                template: template,
                components: {
                    'temperature': Temperature
                }
            })

            return createElement(
                'div',
                {
                    class: {
                        instructions: true
                    }
                },
                [
                    createElement(component)
                ]
            )
       }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Cool, I like this approach. Not far from what I have, really... I'll test it ASAP and let you know!

Comment: Literally a perfect solution for dynamic component rendering with HTML injection. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Here is my approach, not sure if it is what you are after. It introduces a intermediate component to render stuff dynamically. Also, I modified Instructions.vue a bit for my testing, you can modify to fit your shortcode parser

**Instructions.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input type="text" @input="parseInput" />
    <DynamicComponent :type="parsedType" :props="parsedProps"></DynamicComponent>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import DynamicComponent from './DynamicComponent';


export default {
  components: {
    DynamicComponent
  },
  data() {
    return {
      parsedType: '',
      parsedProps: ''
    };
  },
  methods: {
    parseInput(e) { // parse the input
      if (e.target.value === '[temp c=200]') { // change this to use your parser
        this.parsedType = 'Temperature';
        this.parsedProps = { celsius: 200 };
      } else {
        this.parsedType = '';
        this.parsedProps = '';
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

**DynamicComponent.vue**

```
<script>
import Temperature from './Temperature';
// import all other dynamically rendered components


export default {
  components: {
    // let it know what components are there
    Temperature
  },
  props: ['type', 'props'],
  render(h) {
    return h(this.type, {
      props: this.props
    }, this.$slots.default);
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: A very interesting approach, and looks quite clean. I'll test it out as soon as I get the chance and will get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

Currently there is no step where you template is compiled that's why it's rendered as text. I think you could do the following to replace text with component

1. Once you find the temperature wrap it in html element
2. Create new Vue instance in JavaScript (not as html template in string)
3. Mount vue instance on the top of that element using el option or $mount
4. Use interpolation instead of v-html to prevent XSS https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/syntax.html#Text

Comment: Code-wise how would that look in the example I gave?